# Koala::Facebook::AuthenticationError , user has changed the password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, koala

I am using devise , omniauth and koala.

but sometimes (not often of course) I get the following error:

> Koala::Facebook::AuthenticationError: type: OAuthException, code: 190, error_subcode: 460, message: Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password. [HTTP 400]

from this code:

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(params[:access_token])
@user = graph.get_object("me")
```

so the second line is the one causing the exception. what could be wrong with my implementation? should handle that error in some special way? like getting a new token from facebook somehow? or is it just wrong I am even getting this error?

thanks

Comment: Try to renew oauth token. and check again.